# "fsub infinity, infinity" gives 0 in st0 in gcc optimized code

Tags: gcc, assembly, floating-point

I have a code that works fine in -O0 mode and but gives wrong results with -O2. Basically it's something like

```
double x1 = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
double x2 = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
double x = x1 - x2;
```

but the problem happens with the assembly command fsub:

```
fsub %st(1),%st
```

I tried to reproduce this in a small test app, compiled with exactly same compilation flags, and when it comes to the above fsub instruction, the st(0) and st(1) registers contain the same "inf" value, and $fctrl register is same - but somehow in the real app with -O2 the fsub instruction produces 0 (zero) in the st(0) register, instead of -nan.

Also if I compile with -ffloat-store or do printf of x1/x2/x address, then it works fine. From what I see in -O0 version it does fsub with one operand in register and second in memory. But in small test app the fsub is exactly same, working on two same registers, and still it produces correct results.

What can be the reason of such a strange behavior?

Comment: "something like" is hard to comment on. Possibly yet another manifestation of the 387 excess precision?

Comment: Maybe, but the question is how same instruction, operating on same register values, with same coprocessor control flags, can give different results? I.e. control flags are same => 387 in same precision mode, am I correct?

Comment: How did you check the content of the registers? Any chance some long double->double rounding took place then?

Comment: I do check them with print $st0/1 in gdb just before the fsub instruction, and also do printf("%a") in code, the values are same (inf). Can any precision adjustment be applied to infinity values?

Comment: Did you try `info float`?